# Calculate the integral using the Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 -1}$

Calculate $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ where $\gamma(t) = i + e^{it}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$ using the  Cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{z}{z^2-1}=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)}$ and this function is holomorphic inside circle $\displaystyle \gamma(t) = i + e^{it}$ (singularities $1$ and $-1$ are outside), so the integral is $0$.

$\bf{Edit:}$ If you consider $\displaystyle \frac{z}{z^2+1}$ you can write it as $\displaystyle \frac{z}{z^2+1}=\frac{z}{(z-i)(z+i)}$ and use Cauchy integral formula for function $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+i}$, because $f$ is holomorphic inside circle ($-i$ is outside). Cauchy integral formula is $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\omega-i|=1}\frac{f(\omega)}{\omega-z} d\omega$ for $z$ inside circle $|z-i|=1$, if you substitute $z=i$ you get:

$$f(i)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z-i|=1} \frac{z}{z^2+1} dz$$

Finally $f(i)=\frac{i}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks!!! If the signal of denominator f(z) is positive (z^2 +1), the singularities will be -i and i, how it will look?

Comment: Just one singularit is inside the circle?

Comment: I've written what you can do in case $z^2+1$.

Comment: Okkk!! 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\partial\gamma:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z-i|\le1\}\implies \pm1\notin\partial\gamma\implies\int\limits_\gamma\frac z{z^2-1}dz=0$$